# Django custom SQL operator

Tags: python, django, django-models, operators, django-postgresql

I am using `Django 1.5.3` and `PostgreSQL` for my project. There are `CIDR` type fields in my tables and I wanted to model it in Django. I am using a `CIDRField` like ;

```
class CIDRField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CIDRField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "CIDR"

    def to_python(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        # Convert value to pure network address to prevent
        # PostgreSQL exception
        if IP.prefix(value):
            return IP.prefix(value).first.prefix
```

When I query on the table with the `CIDRField`, I must use `raw` instead of `filter`;

```
select * from ip_table where ip<<'0.0.0.0/0'
```

Bu I also have another fields that is non CIDRField and I dont want to construct all queries about this table with `raw`. There is also no way I see to use both of them.

Maybe I can customize CIDRField more than that and I can use filter instead of raw to query on CIDRField. For example can I customize `gt`, `gte`, `lt` or `lte` lookup functions?. Can they be looking for `<<`,`<<=`,`>>`,`>>=` instead of `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`. Can I customize this operators in Django?

Thank you.